# Does raw vis provided from vis sources have to be extracted by magi?

Tags: ars-magica-5

The basic rules indicate that the area around a covenant can provide some amount of raw vis per year (p 72).  Does that raw vis need to be extracted as per the vis extraction rules in the laboratory section (p 94)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ars p.72 is about designing vis sources for the covenant (5 build points per pawn per year), which do not need to be extracted using a lab activity. These sources need to be collected, and might be contested or temporary depending on what other aspects you choose in covenant creation. These vis sources are generally considered a repeating source available each year.
Vis extraction (Ars p.94) is for extracting additional vis, and is not a repeating source.
A covenant vis source can be of any type, as described in the setting. Vis extracted from an aura in a lab is always Vim.

Comment: So the vis from covenant sources does not need to be extracted? How does the vis from the laboratory extraction differ from the covenant sources?

Comment: @Grosscol - For starters, extracted vis is always Vim vis, while collected vis can be of any Art. Also, extracted vis has the physical form given to it by the extracting magus, while collected vis will have whatever form it naturally occurred in. e.g., If the covenant has an apple tree which produces 10 Herbam vis per year, that vis will be contained in the apples (and, thus, can be collected by anyone who knows which apples to pick).

Comment: Great answer Dave! Spot on.